# Find words in table based off prefix

Tags: database, sqlite, indexing

I'm curious what the best way to store and retrieve a large number of words based on a prefix. The table will contain ~200,000 words. I need to find/return all matching words based on a given prefix (which is 2 characters long)

Ex. Table contains = "abc" "abcd" aef"

given the prefix "ab" returns "abc", "abcd"

What I currently have is:

```
select *
from table
where word like 'ab%'
```

But I don't feel this is the best implementation

Comment: as long as you have indexed the column, and you have something before the % this should work fine.  You will run into problems if you search for something like %cd, or %b%, but xx% will use the index just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This query is very efficient if SQLite can use an index for this lookup.

`LIKE` is case insensitive, so

- the column must have `TEXT` [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), i.e., it should be declared as `word TEXT` or something like that; and
- the index must be [created as case insensitive](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html), i.e., something like this:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX MyTable_word_index ON MyTable(word COLLATE NOCASE);
  ```

---

If you want a case sensitive comparison, you could use any normal index and some normal comparison operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE word >= 'ab'
  AND word <  'ac'
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE word LIKE 'ab%'`

Comment: Is there nothing more efficient?

Comment: Improve efficient need consume space or memory.

1.You may create more field base on prefix.You can directely compare the filed to prefix.

2.Load table to memory in the application.Then search word from the memory.Maybe you can use linq if code C#.

Comment: if I were to create two columns one for the 2 character prefix and the other for the remainder of the word would this be more efficient?

Comment: You may create table like hash table and try it.